# how to make beautiful scatter3d using R with rowname as legend and different colors

Tags: r, annotations, label, scatterplot3d

I have made 3d scatter plot using but i want color each dot differently and different shape

Code I used

```
NB = read.csv("PCA_LuoyuanBay.csv")
head(NB)
library(scatterplot3d)

zz <- scatterplot3d(NB[,2:3], 
                    xlab = "PC-1", ylab = "PC-2", zlab = "PC-3", 
                    pch = 16, color = "blue", grid = TRUE)
zz.coords <- zz$xyz.convert(NB[,2:3]) 
text(zz.coords$x, 
     zz.coords$y,             
     labels = NB[,1],               
     cex = .5, 
     pos = 4)
```

Data i used for this analysis.

```
dput(Mydata)
```

structure(list(Pollutant = c("Petrolium", "Sulfide", "PAH", "OCP", "PES",
"Acrylic", "PP", "Rayon"), PC1 = c(0.403932362147421, 0.555044525557921,
0.076054416943299, -0.0720241904196998, 0.447560520426065, 0.0568903915498196,
-0.259187304098997, 0.497058817862777), PC2 = c(-0.455434537323988,
-0.29106034461361, 0.342721781548768, 0.117145627891435, 0.408367154179987,
0.506743327637759, -0.390124826686555, 0.0305291206586067), PC3 = c(0.0862562754659925,
-0.0387696672317506, 0.574038320104521, -0.721513535016868, 0.158526945855976,
-0.108410486624353, 0.222722390860155, -0.233379742311754), PC4 = c(-0.314407751462903,
-0.134408332997354, 0.169766921910276, -0.0832028345129114, -0.164199259363002,
-0.696041503283991, -0.456572272090939, 0.356994727809195), PC5 = c(0.0161942986358165,
0.015757794327504, 0.598159844933004, 0.558520586006352, -0.029362526526301,
-0.118504522623422, 0.498083095703882, 0.258373259944396), PC6 = c(0.518412858988302,
-0.0191704059743438, 0.361419582163633, 0.24044643261062, -0.329200673343559,
0.0430271919863158, -0.521248888676183, -0.400645947586656),
PC7 = c(0.151901296559833, -0.205320742751646, -0.144538332512259,
0.265500760968266, 0.686586857523377, -0.46642589723511,
0.0106988593210088, -0.392833691188813), PC8 = c(0.480663601925481,
-0.738151978534111, -0.0954256850387164, -0.115475274210577,
0.0140322623771219, 0.10149037686373, 0.0515695472255115,
0.434162341603549)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-8L))

Answer (score 1):

You could try plotly for some nice features

```
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(NB, x = ~PC1, y = ~PC2, z = ~PC3)
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'PC-1'),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'PC-2'),
                                   zaxis = list(title = 'PC-3')))

fig
```